# What size wire do I need for a 100 amp service from meter base?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

My run is 80 feet underground in 2 inch conduit from 200 amp breaker to a 100 amp service panel in a detached garage. What size wire should be used?

Comment: Does the sub-panel have a main breaker or just lugs?

Comment: #1 aluminum, by the way... or #3Cu.   You cannot use #2Al or #4Cu, though many will claim you can.  You can't.  Really.